# how to round the decimal value in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rounding

I want to round the value from 1572.750000 to 1572.75

```
SELECT ROUND(1572.750000, 2)
```

I tried above format, but it was not working.
Please any one help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you Can use this

```
SELECT cast(1572.750000 as decimal(15,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to convert to `decimal`:

```
select cast(1572.750000 as decimal(10, 2))
```

If you want a string output, you can use the `str()` function (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)).

The confusion occurs because `round()` changes the *value*, but it does not change the *type*.  Hence, whatever application is using the value can format it as it wants.  When the application knows that the value has only two decimal places (with `decimal(10, 2)`) or the code converts directly to a string, then this is not an issue.

Comment: Gordon Linoff  it is showing Incorrect syntax near '1572.750000'.

Comment: @kartheekij . . . Either `convert(decimal(10, 2), <val>)` or `cast(<val> as decimal(10, 2))`.